# C++ "delete []" operator removes only 2 first values

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, delete-operator

I just started learning C++ and I have hard time understanding how delete [] operator works. I wrote a code to see how it works but it removes only first 2 elements of an array. My question is how do I delete an array?

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int size;
    cout << "Size: ";
    cin >> size;
    int * pt = new int [size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        pt[i] = i + 1;
        cout << "Addrres: " << &pt[i] << " " << "Index: " << i << " "
             << "Value: " << pt[i] << " "   << endl;
    }
    cout << "----------DELETING----------" << endl;
    delete [] pt;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << "Address: " << &pt[i] << " " << "Index: " << i << " "
             << "Value: " << pt[i] << " "   << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example result form my terminal is:

```
Size: 5
Address: 0x55d3060e4690 Index: 0 Value: 1 
Address: 0x55d3060e4694 Index: 1 Value: 2 
Address: 0x55d3060e4698 Index: 2 Value: 3 
Address: 0x55d3060e469c Index: 3 Value: 4 
Address: 0x55d3060e46a0 Index: 4 Value: 5 
----------DELETING----------
Address: 0x55d3060e4690 Index: 0 Value: 0 
Address: 0x55d3060e4694 Index: 1 Value: 0 
Address: 0x55d3060e4698 Index: 2 Value: 3 
Address: 0x55d3060e469c Index: 3 Value: 4 
Address: 0x55d3060e46a0 Index: 4 Value: 5
```

I'm begginer when it comes to programming so I don't know it this is necessary but im running Linux Mint 64bit. Compiler used is g++.

Comment: After `delete [] pt;` write `pt = nullptr`. When you do a second output your array already not exists. [FYI](https://www.cryptologie.net/article/419/zeroing-memory-compiler-optimizations-and-memset_s/)

Comment: You deleted the memory you allocated before. Deleting means removing it from the set of usable memory to the program. It does not mean that the bits which were used before should be overwritten. Your second loop looks at the content of these bits, but you are looking at memory which is not in the scope of your program anymore. A tool like Valgrind will tell you that you are accessing bytes which are not allocated by the program.

Comment: C++ offers no means of checking whether pointer or reference point at valid items. It is always programmers responsibility to ensure that the value being accessed was not deallocated / did not went out of scope. Also the method of checking whether item is "removed" in this case is completely wrong because it assumes that "removed" value becomes `0` while in reality `int` has trivial destructor so `delete []` only preforms memory deallocation without any concern for array content.

Comment: If you use Visual Studio and compile a DEBUG version, it will help you find that kind of bug. There are surely similar tools for other compilers. The reason the first few bytes change is probably because they are used to track available memory (think free blocks chain). All this is undefined/unspecified so compiler could do what they want with freed memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Elements are not *necessarily* removed when you `delete[]` them. They are just made available to the system for re-use. Accessing them afterwards is not allowed (Undefined Behaviour).

If your array had held objects with destructors then `delete` also causes destructors to be run before making the memory available for re-use.

Comment: So delete operator makes that address available again. For example another array that is created could use the same addresses, since that adress is freed, correct?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to actually see how delete [] works, you need to try something like this

```
 class X42
 {
 public:
    virtual ~X42 () { cout << "Deleting " << this < endl ; } ;
 } ;


X42 *ptr = new X42 [42] ;
delete [] ptr ;
```

There is no destructor for int so nothing specific happens to the array elements in your delete. They become undefined values. It just so happens that your memory deallocator is only trashing some of the values in the deleted memory.